# On multiple request mysql connection giving Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

I am using jsch for ssh connection and by port forwarding, i am connecting to MySQL. and it's dynamic connection. Hosts are not fixed so can't use a connection pool.

```
public void connect(String host, String username, String password,SshProperties sshProperies) throws SshException {
    if (port <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument Port should be positive value");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(host)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument Host can not be null or blank");
    }
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        session.setConfig(STRICT_HOSTKEY_CHECKIN_KEY, STRICT_HOSTKEY_CHECKIN_VALUE);
        session.connect(100000);
        logger.info("Connection established to host:{} and port:{}", host, port);int assigned_port;
        assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL("0.0.0.0", 0, sshProperies.getHost(), sshProperies.getDbPort());
        logger.info("Port forwording to host {} and port {}", sshProperies.getHost(), sshProperies.getDbPort());
        DBProperties dbprop = new DBProperties(host, assigned_port, sshProperies.getDbUsername(), sshProperies.getDbPassword());
        mysqlConnector.connect(dbprop);
        List<String> db = mysqlConnector.getDatabases();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        logger.error("Error connecting to host {}", host, e);
        throw new SshException(e);
    }
}
```

for mysql connection i use this method

```
public void connect(DBProperties properties) throws ConnectorException {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(properties.getIp())) {
        logger.error("Ip/Host cannont be null or empty");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ip/Host cannont be null or empty");
    }
    if (properties.getPort() <= 0 && properties.getPort() >= 65536) {
        logger.error("Port should be inbetween 0 and 65536");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }
    try {
        logger.debug("Connecting to MySQL DB");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + properties.getUrl() + "?useSSL=false";
        logger.debug("Connecting to URL {}", url);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
        logger.debug("Connected to {} : {}", connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName(), connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion());
        if(!connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion().contains(SUPPORTED_VERSION)){
            logger.error("MySQL version not supported {}",connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion());
            throw new ConnectorException("MySQL version not supported", new UnsupportedClassVersionError("MySQL version not supported"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error while connecting {}", e);
        throw new ConnectorException("Invalid DB credentials", e);
    }
}
```

**Error**:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 73 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 51 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:590)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:57)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1421)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2443)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1739)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.baffle.common.connector.db.MySQLConnector_5_7_17.connect(MySQLConnector_5_7_17.java:53)
    at com.baffle.common.connector.ssh.SshConnectorImpl.connectToDatabaseBySSH(SshConnectorImpl.java:111)
    at com.baffle.common.connector.ssh.SshConnectorImpl.lambda$0(SshConnectorImpl.java:139)
    at com.baffle.common.connector.ssh.SshConnectorImpl$$Lambda$1/230835489.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 73 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 51 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:527)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:723)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sendCommand(MysqlaProtocol.java:662)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaProtocol.java:950)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaSession.java:431)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1974)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:60)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:48)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:51)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:521)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

I think error comes when one thread is disconnecting and other is trying to connect.

Comment: What/where are you getting the error?  (i.e. stack trace)